# Oracle Sql ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hello there I'm having trouble finding with my sql code.

here are the codes that I made so far:

```
create table Client_Info
(
    "Client_Name" varchar2 (30) primary key,
    "Birthday" date not null,
    "Zip_Code" number(4) not null,
    "Weapon_Rank" number(1) not null,
    "Registration_Date" date not null
)

create table Ammunition_Info
(
    "Ammo_Id" number(8) primary key,
    "Ammo_Type" varchar2(30) not null,
    "Ammo_Round" varchar2(30) not null,
    "Amount" number(2)not null
)

create table Gun_Info
(
    "Serial_Number" number(8) primary key,
    "Model_Name" varchar2(20) not null,
    "Clasification" varchar(20) not null,
    "Year_of_production" date not null,
    "Weapon_Rank" number(1) not null,
    "Ammo_Type" varchar2(30) not null,
    "Ammo_Round" varchar2(30) not null,

    constraint wrank_fk foreign key("Weapon_Rank") references Client_Info("Weapon_Rank"),
    constraint amt_fk foreign key("Ammo_Type") references Ammunition_Info("Ammo_Type"),
    constraint amr_fk foreign key("Ammo_Round") references Ammunition_Info("Ammo_Round")
)
```

The error appears when I try to link foreign keys in the Gun_Info table and I don't know what went wrong

Can someone point out what mistakes that I made

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  Your foreign key references should be to the *primary key* in each of the referenced tables.  What do you not understand?

Comment: oh, thanks for pointing that out i don't know how that flew over my head @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff Primary Key or unique constrained columns

Comment: @astentx . . . Foreign key references *should* be to primary keys, even if they are allowed on unique keys.

Comment: BTW having Client_name as a primary key is a really bad idea. There are many reasons for this, for example how would you handle 2 different people with the same name?

Comment: As a side observation, By creating your column names enclosed in double-quotes, you are creating case-sensitive names.  This will come back to bite you.  If you want to write them mixed-case, that's fine but leave out the the double-quotes so that they won't be case sensitive, thus forcing you to _always_ enclose them -- and use the exact case with which they were created.

Comment: Another size observation - zip codes are not _numbers_, they are character strings that - in the US - are limited to numeric _characters_.  Any time you declare something as a _number_ you will lose any leading zeros.  Basic rule: if it is illogical to do arithmetic on the element, then it is not a number and should not be declared as such.

Comment: Also in passing, if you put the FK constraint info inline with the column definition, you can skip the datatype and let it inherit from the parent. In my view this is better practice than repeating it. e.g. `weapon_rank constraint wrank_fk references Client_Info(Weapon_Rank)`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, code that *creates* those tables might look like this:

```
SQL> create table client_info
  2  (   client_id         number constraint pk_clinfo primary key,
  3      client_name       varchar2 (30) not null,
  4      birthday          date not null,
  5      zip_code          varchar2(4) not null,
  6      weapon_rank       number(1) not null,
  7      registration_date date not null,
  8      --
  9      constraint uk_clinfo unique (weapon_rank)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> create table ammunition_info
  2  (   ammo_id    number(8) constraint pk_amminfo primary key,
  3      ammo_type  varchar2(30) not null,
  4      ammo_round varchar2(30) not null,
  5      amount     number(2)not null,
  6      --
  7      constraint uk_amminfo unique (ammo_type, ammo_round)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> create table gun_info
  2  (   serial_number      number(8) constraint pk_gunifo primary key,
  3      model_name         varchar2(20) not null,
  4      clasification      varchar(20) not null,
  5      year_of_production date not null,
  6      weapon_rank        number(1) not null,
  7      ammo_type          varchar2(30) not null,
  8      ammo_round         varchar2(30) not null,
  9      --
 10      constraint wrank_fk foreign key(weapon_rank)
 11        references client_info    (weapon_rank),
 12      constraint amt_fk   foreign key(ammo_type, ammo_round)
 13        references ammunition_info(ammo_type, ammo_round)
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

What did I do?

- added `client_id` as a primary key column to `client_info` table
- named all constraints (otherwise Oracle generates *generic* name which isn't descriptive at all
- removed all double quotes to make tables and columns case insensitive
- changed zip code from `number` datatype to `varchar2`
- added unique keys to `client_info` and `ammunition_info` so that they could be referenced from `gun_info`. I don't know whether that's what you really need

I'd also suggest you to re-read comments posted below your question and try to understand what people have said & why.